# how can i manipulate walls in three.js

Tags: three.js

i have this project where i want to create a room and manipulate it using react three.js
I'm not that familiar with the tool so i faced some problems

here is the full code and thanks to anyone that can help

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";
import "/resources/css/style.css";

export default function Three2() {
    useEffect(() => {
        // CAMERA
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1500);
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera.position.z = 40;
        const geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 32);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        const circle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        camera.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 4, 0);

        const canvas = document.getElementById("myTHREE");

        let walls = [];

        // RENDERER
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x35637c);

        let right = false;
        let left = false;

        let wallThickness = 0.5;

        /*
        // CUBE
        let selectedWidth = 4, selectedDepth = 1, selectedLength = 5;
        const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(selectedWidth, selectedDepth, selectedLength);
        const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000,
        });
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.position.set(0, 1, 0);
        scene.add(cube);
        cube.userData.draggable  = true;
        cube.userData.name = "wall1";
        cube.userData.rotatable = true;
*/
        // lights
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        directionalLight.position.set(0, 10, 0);
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        function animate() {
            dragObject();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            updateWalls();
        }

        let hemiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
        scene.add(hemiLight);

        let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        dirLight.position.set(-30, 50, -30);
        scene.add(dirLight);
        dirLight.castShadow = true;
        dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.left = -70;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.right = 70;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.top = 70;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -70;

        const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); 
        const clickMouse = new THREE.Vector2(); 
        const moveMouse = new THREE.Vector2(); 
        let draggable;
        let rotatable;
        let wall;

        let isDragging = false;

        function intersect(pos) {
            raycaster.setFromCamera(pos, camera);
            return raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
        }

        let Right = false ;

        window.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
            draggable = null;
            rotatable = null;
            controls.enabled = true;
            Right = false ;
        });
        
        let selectedWall = null;

        window.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
            if (event.button === 2) {
                controls.enabled = false;
                Right = true;
            } else if (event.button === 0) {
                clickMouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                clickMouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                const found = intersect(clickMouse);
                if (found.length > 0) {
                    if (found[0].object.userData.draggable) {
                        draggable = found[0].object;
                        isDragging = true;
                        console.log(`found draggable ${draggable.userData.name}`);
                        controls.enabled = false;
                    } else if (found[0].object.userData.wall) {
                        selectedWall = found[0].object;
                        selectWall();
                        console.log(`Intersected with wall: ${selectedWall.userData.name}`);
                        controls.enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        
        function selectWall() {
            walls.forEach(wall => {
                if (wall === selectedWall) {
                    wall.material.color.set(0xff0000);
                } else {
                    wall.material.color.set(0xffffff);
                }
            });
        }

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
            moveMouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            moveMouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
            const found = intersect(clickMouse);
        
            if (Right) {
                for (let i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
                    if (found[i].object.userData.draggable) {
                        rotatable = found[i].object;
                        const rotatableBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(rotatable);
                        let collisionDetected = false;
                        let direction = false;

                        for (let j = 0; j < walls.length; j++) {
                            const wallBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(walls[j]);
                            if (rotatableBox.intersectsBox(wallBox)) {
                                console.log("Collision with wall");
                                collisionDetected = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
        
                        if (collisionDetected) {
                            console.log(`found rotatable ${rotatable.userData.name}`);
                            rotatable.rotation.y -= moveMouse.x * 0.1; 
                        } else {
                            rotatable.rotation.y += moveMouse.x * 0.1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        function updateWalls() {
            const sceneRotation = scene.rotation.clone();
          
            const isRoomRotatedX = Math.abs(sceneRotation.x) > Math.PI / 4;
            const isRoomRotatedY = Math.abs(sceneRotation.y) > Math.PI / 4;
            const isRoomRotatedZ = Math.abs(sceneRotation.z) > Math.PI / 4;
          
            walls.forEach(wall => {
              const wallPosition = wall.position.clone();
        
              wallPosition.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -sceneRotation.x);
              wallPosition.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), -sceneRotation.y);
              wallPosition.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), -sceneRotation.z);

              let isCoveringInside = false;
              if (isRoomRotatedX) {
                isCoveringInside = wallPosition.x < 0;
              }
              if (isRoomRotatedY) {
                isCoveringInside = wallPosition.y < 0;
              }
              if (isRoomRotatedZ) {
                isCoveringInside = wallPosition.z < 0;
              }
          
              if (isCoveringInside) {
                const newGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(wall.geometry.parameters.width, wall.geometry.parameters.height, wall.geometry.parameters.depth * 0.2);
                wall.geometry.dispose();
                wall.geometry = newGeometry;
              }
            });
          }

        function dragObject() {
            if (draggable != null) {
                const found = intersect(moveMouse);
                if (found.length > 0) {
                    let target;
                    for (let i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
                        if (!found[i].object.userData.ground) continue;
                        let wall = walls[i];
                        target = found[i].point; 
                        const draggableBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(draggable);
                        const wallBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(wall);
                        if (draggableBox.intersectsBox(wallBox)) {
                            console.log("Collision with wall");
                            isTouchingWall = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            isTouchingWall = false ;
                        }
                    }

                    if (target) {
                        const dimensions = new THREE.Vector3();
                        const draggableBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(draggable);
                        draggableBox.getSize(dimensions);

                        const minX = -platformWidth / 2 + dimensions.x / 2;
                        const maxX = platformWidth / 2 - dimensions.x / 2;
                        const minZ = -platformLength / 2 + dimensions.z / 2;
                        const maxZ = platformLength / 2 - dimensions.z / 2;

                        const clampedX = Math.min(Math.max(target.x, minX), maxX);
                        const clampedZ = Math.min(Math.max(target.z, minZ), maxZ);

                        draggable.position.x = clampedX;
                        draggable.position.z = clampedZ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let down = false ;
        let created = false;
        let blockPlane, wall1, wall2, wall3, wall4;
        
        function saveData() {
            const widthInput = document.getElementById("width");
            const lengthInput = document.getElementById("length");
            const depthInput = document.getElementById("depth");
            
            const width = parseFloat(widthInput.value * 10);
            const length = parseFloat(lengthInput.value * 10);
            const depth = parseFloat(depthInput.value * 10);
        
            let platformHeight = 0.1;
        
            if (!created) {
                blockPlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, platformHeight, length),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x5A5A5A }));
        
                blockPlane.userData.ground = true;
                scene.add(blockPlane);
        
                const wallThickness = 0.5;
                const wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        
                wall1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, depth, wallThickness), wallMaterial);
                wall1.position.set(0, depth / 2, length / 2 + wallThickness / 2);
                scene.add(wall1);
                wall1.userData.name = "wall1";
        
                wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, depth, wallThickness), wallMaterial);
                wall2.position.set(0, depth / 2, -length / 2 - wallThickness / 2);
                scene.add(wall2);
                wall2.userData.name = "wall2";
        
                wall3 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(wallThickness, depth, length), wallMaterial);
                wall3.position.set(-width / 2 - wallThickness / 2, depth / 2, 0);
                scene.add(wall3);
                wall3.userData.name = "wall3";
        
                wall4 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(wallThickness, depth, length), wallMaterial);
                wall4.position.set(width / 2 + wallThickness / 2, depth / 2, 0);
                scene.add(wall4);
                wall4.userData.name = "wall4";

                wall1.userData.wall = true;
                wall2.userData.wall = true;
                wall3.userData.wall = true;
                wall4.userData.wall = true;

                walls.push(wall1);
                walls.push(wall2);
                walls.push(wall3);
                walls.push(wall4);

                created = true;
            } else {
                scene.remove(blockPlane, wall1, wall2, wall3, wall4);
        
                blockPlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, platformHeight, length),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x5A5A5A }));
                blockPlane.userData.ground = true;
                scene.add(blockPlane);
        
                const wallThickness = 0.5;
                const wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        
                wall1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, depth, wallThickness), wallMaterial);
                wall1.position.set(0, depth / 2, length / 2 + wallThickness / 2);
                scene.add(wall1);
        
                wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, depth, wallThickness), wallMaterial);
                wall2.position.set(0, depth / 2, -length / 2 - wallThickness / 2);
                scene.add(wall2);
        
                wall3 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(wallThickness, depth, length), wallMaterial);
                wall3.position.set(-width / 2 - wallThickness / 2, depth / 2, 0);
                scene.add(wall3);
        
                wall4 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(wallThickness, depth, length), wallMaterial);
                wall4.position.set(width / 2 + wallThickness / 2, depth / 2, 0);
                scene.add(wall4);

            }
            scene.children.push(wall1, wall2, wall3, wall4);
            console.log(`Width: ${width}, Length: ${length}, Depth: ${depth}`);
            const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu");
            dropdownMenu.style.display = "none";
        }
        
        document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", saveData);
        document.getElementById("floatingButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
            if (!down){
                dropdownMenu.style.display = "inline-block";
                down = true ;
            }
            else{
                dropdownMenu.style.display = "none";
                down = false ;
            }
        });

        function updatewalls() {
            
        }
        
    
        // CONTROLS
        let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        animate();
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <button id="floatingButton"></button>
            <div id="dropdownMenu" className="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Width</a>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Width" id="width" />
                <br />
                <a href="#">Length</a>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Length" id="length" />
                <br />
                <a href="#">Depth</a>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Depth" id="depth" />
                <br />
                <button id="save">Save</button>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myTHREE"></canvas>
        </div>
    );
}
```

problem 1 :
in the mousedown event listener when there is an intersection with a wall i want that specific wall to be colored different but the problem i faced is that whenever i click on the wall4 they all change color to red and when i press on any other wall they go back white

problem 2 :
i have the function update walls so it reads the rotation of the scene and updates any wall to get reduced height whenever its covering the inside of the room but yet its not working

Comment: `problem 2 ... its not working` you need to detail what is not working

Comment: It is solved ty

Answer (score 0):

1. You are use the same material for each wall, you want each wall to have it's own material, you achieve that with [`Material.clone()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.clone).

Comment: Ok I'll try it but problem 2 is solved